# How to reproduce: Script Error, "Object does not support this property or method."

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Can any one give me a scripts (HTML/CSS/Javascript) that can reproduce this error on `IE 7.0`? I am trying to fix this bug in my page where I get this warning but could not exactly found the problem. Line number does not match with the source either.

I thought the better approach would be to create a bug and then work on it incrementally rather than making some wild guess!

Comment: You'd need to post the CamMenuModify.htm file in its entirety for us to even begin to know what is causing that error.

Comment: That is just en example I found on the internet on HP website. I cannot give the source code.

Comment: --I am trying to fix this bug in my page where I get this warning -- If you get this warning in your page, then supply us with the page source so we can diagose it.

Comment: As I said I cannot give the source code. It looks like you also get the same warning in one of your page, why don't you put your source code?

Comment: Warning in what page that is mine?

Answer (score 2):

As Shog said, that error will occur when you try to call a method on an object which doesn't have that method.

This is most often caused by an object being null when you expect it to, well, not be null.

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('myElement');
myEl.appendChild(...)
```

The above example will cause that error if the "#myElement" element doesn't exist.

If it's only happening on IE and not Firefox, chances are it's because you're using a method which IE doesn't support.

The solution? You can try the Script Debugger, but I've never found that to be useful myself. The most reliable, yet painfully slow method is alert() debugging. At strategic points through your code, put in an alert with a unique message. At some point IE will throw an error, so you'll know that the error is somewhere between the last alert which you saw, and the next one which didn't.

```
function myFunc() {
    alert('a');
    var myEl = document.getElementById('myElement');
    myEl.appendChild(something);
    alert('b');
    // more code
}
```

if you ran that and you saw 'a' but not 'b' you know it's in between there somewhere. This is just the sad state of javascript in IE, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your code follow the jslint.com rules, it will go away.
It will also point you at exactly where the issue is in your code.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought the better approach would be
>   to create a bug and then work on it
>   incrementally rather than making some
>   wild guess!

You would be wrong. There are countless scenarios that could produce the error you are seeing. All it means is that you're trying to call an undefined method. For instance:

```
var blah = {};
blah.methodWhichDoesntExist(); // <-- error
```

This could be the result of a typo, an undetected failure in some other component, or gamma rays consistently flipping bits in your HTML right after you save. Hard to be any more specific without knowing more about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

For IE, download the [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2f465be0-94fd-4569-b3c4-dffdf19ccd99&displaylang=en)

Comment: The problem is that I don't get this warning/error when I enable the Script debug(IE + Other), so I cannot put a break point either.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed a similar bug by using IE8 and switching it into IE7 mode. You then get a more specific error message telling you which line of which file is failing.

After that set a breakpoint so that the code stops just before the offending line (F12 to get to debugger tools, then choose the JS file you want from the 'scripts' dropdown and click to the left of the line number. Click 'start debugging' to make it use the breakpoints).

As others have pointed out, this error could have many causes, but in my case, I had two IDs on the same page with one capitalised and one not. getElementById() was getting the wrong one. Only IE7 complained.